# Continuous function from standard topology to K-topology

Tags: general-topology

I am just going through a practice problem and need to show that, where f(x)=x as the identity function.

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R_{k}}$ where $\mathbb{R_{k}} = \{(a,b)- \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} \}$

now we know that $\mathbb{R_{k}}$ is finer than the standard topology given $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R_{k}}$

My logic here is to look at $f^{-1}( (a,b) -K)$ = $f^{-1}(a,b) \cap f^{-1}(K^{c})$  , clearly $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, but what about the $f^{-1}(K^{c})$?  for me I think if we omit all of the terms $\frac{1}{n}$ what is left is a bunch of tiny open intervals, so we can take arbitrary unions of a bunch of tiny intervals that skip over these omitted points. where the arbitrary unions of open sets that skip over these intervals, is open.  but how to show this?  We know that the basis for $\mathbb{R_{k}}$ is contained in the standard topology basis, so this means we can take a bunch of unions to generate the standard topology.

so I am sure this is continuous, but how to show it?  I am stuck.  what about the inverse of $f$ given :

$f^{-1}: \mathbb{R_{k}} \to \mathbb{R}$ this can not be continuous.

Comment: As it stands the question does not make sense: what is the function $f$, and what are you supposed to show about it? It appears that you want to show that it’s continuous, but we still need to know what $f$ is. Is it the identity function, $f(x)=x$? (It’s also the case that your definition of $\mathbb{R}_k$ doesn’t make sense, but I know what you mean and will deal with that after we sort out what the question really is.)

Comment: yes the function f(x) = x as the identity function. I am working from a self made example similar to Munkres example page 104.  He gives an example of a bijection $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R_{l}}$ where $\mathbb{R_{l}}$ is the lower limit topology. this function is not continuous.  but I am interested in changing from the lower limit topology to the K-topology.  and I also think that it will not be continuous.  Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. where g :$\mathbb{R_{l}} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.  (I just wish to compare this example changing to K-topology).  ty

Comment: The identity function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_k$ is not continuous: $U=(-1,1)\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_k$, but $f^{-1}[U]=U$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$: it contains $0$ but not any open nbhd of $0$. However, $f^{-1}$ is continuous, simply because the topology of $\mathbb{R}_k$ is finer than that of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The OP has fixed the question, and I’ve a full answer ready to post whenever it’s re-opened.

Comment: Thank you so much.,  I think the question is open now, can you please post your suggestion and idea?  thank you!

Comment: Done; let me know if anything’s unclear.

Comment: I will read through tonight, may not respond until tomorrow. thank you

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s get the statement of the problem fixed first. $\mathbb{R}_k$ is *not* equal to $\left\{(a,b)\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}\right\}$, or even to $\left\{(a,b)\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }a<b\right\}$; as a set $\mathbb{R}_k$ is simply $\mathbb{R}$, the real line. What you mean is that $\mathbb{R}_k$ denotes the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology for which

$$\left\{(a,b)\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }a<b\right\}$$

is a base.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_k:x\mapsto x$ be the identity function, and for convenience let $K=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$. To see that $f$ is **not** continuous, let $U=(-1,1)\setminus K$; by definition $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_k$. However, $f^{-1}[U]=U$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, because $0\in U$, but there is no $\epsilon>0$ such that $0\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq U$.

On the other hand, $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}_k\to\mathbb{R}$ **is** continuous: this follows automatically from the fact that the topology of $\mathbb{R}_k$ is finer than that of $\mathbb{R}$. To see this clearly, let $\mathscr{E}$ be the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathscr{T}$ be the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $U$ be any open set in $\mathscr{R}$; then $U\in\mathscr{E}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, so

$$\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}\left[U\right]=U\in\mathscr{T}$$

is open in $\mathbb{R}_k$, and $f^{-1}$ is therefore continuous.

More generally, you should try to prove that if $\mathscr{T}_0$ and $\mathscr{T}_1$ are topologies on a set $X$ such that $\mathscr{T}_0\subseteq\mathscr{T}_1$, then the identity map on $X$ is always continuous as a map from $\langle X,\mathscr{T}_1\rangle$ to $\langle X,\mathscr{T}_0\rangle$, but as a map from $\langle X,\mathscr{T}_0\rangle$ to $\langle X,\mathscr{T}_1\rangle$ it is continuous if and only if $\mathscr{T}_0=\mathscr{T}_1$. (HINT for the last part: if $\mathscr{T}_0\subsetneqq\mathscr{T}_1$, consider $\operatorname{id}_X^{-1}[U]$ for some $U\in\mathscr{T}_1\setminus\mathscr{T}_0$.)

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}(U)=U$ not open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is it because 0 acts as an isolated point because we minus infinitely many $\frac{1}{n}$ ?  thus there does not exist an open interval around this point?

Comment: I think the proof showing that $\mathbb{T_{0}} \subset \mathbb{T_{1}}$ goes something like: Since $\mathbb{T_{1}}$ is the parent set $\exists U_{\alpha} \notin T_{0}$, where $\forall x_{\alpha} \in T_{0}$  $g(x_{\alpha}) = x_{\alpha} \in T_{0}$.  if for some g($x_{\alpha}) \in U_{\alpha}$ then this violates $U_{\alpha} \notin T_{0}$  since g(x) = x as the identity map implies it sends all the elements in the set, to itself.  Where $U_{\alpha} \notin T_{0}$ must have no pre image.  ?

Comment: @Anthony: If $U$ were open in $\Bbb R$, then for each $x\in U$ there would have to be an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon_x,x+\epsilon_x)\subseteq U$: $U$ would have to contain an open interval around $x$. But $U$ does not contain any such open interval around $0$: no matter what $\epsilon>0$ you try, $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\nsubseteq U$. To see this, just choose $n$ big enough so that $\frac1n<\epsilon$; then $\frac1n\in(-\epsilon,epsilon)\setminus U$.

Comment: @Anthony: I can’t make much sense of your third comment, I’m afraid. What is your $T_0$? If it’s my $\mathscr{T}_0$, then it makes no sense to say that a point of $X$ is an element of $T_0$, because the elements of $\mathscr{T}_0$ are subsets of $X$, not elements of $X$. And if it’s something whose elements *are* points of $X$, then it’s a subset of $X$, in which case it makes no sense even to consider whether $U_\alpha\in T_0$. For the first part of the proposition you need only imitate what I did in proving that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, with $\mathscr{T}_0$ taking the place of ...

Comment: ... $\mathscr{E}$, and $\mathscr{T}_1$ taking the place of $\mathscr{T}$. For the second part, imitate what I did in proving that $f$ is not continuous.